# Display blank fields if there are no records

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to display blank fields if there are no records returned.

Now it is returning null like below -

[image]

Apex Class -

```
   public with sharing class wrapper_test_controller {
        public list<wrapperclass> wrapperelement_for_account{get;set;}
        public list<wrapperclass> wrapperelement_for_contact{get;set;}
        public string selectedproductfamily {get;set;}
        public list<product2> queryResult{get;set;}
        public list<Work_Order_Item__c> queryResult1{get;set;}
        public List<wrapperclass> lstobjfields
                {
                  get;
                  set;
                } 


            public PageReference query() {
            system.debug('@@@'+selectedproductfamily);
                 String qryString = 'SELECT Id,name,family,Measurement_Type__c,Cleaning_Unit_Price__c,Treatment_Unit_Price__c,(select Service__c,Quantity__c,Length__c,Width__c from work_order_items__R) FROM product2 WHERE ' +

                    '(Family like \'%' + selectedproductfamily + '%\')';

                queryResult = Database.query(qryString);


                return null;

            }

        public wrapper_test_controller (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


         }

        public class wrapperclass{
        public String name { get; set; }  
        public Integer data { get; set; }  
        public Product2  account {get;set;}
        public Work_Order_Item__c service {get;set;}

        public wrapperclass(String Name,Integer data) {
        this.name = Name; 
          this.data = data;
         } 
        public wrapperclass (Work_Order_Item__c record){
          this.service = record;

          }

          public wrapperclass (Product2 record1){
          this.account= record1;

         }  

         public wrapperclass (Work_Order_Item__c a, Product2 mh)
                {
                    service = a;
                    account = mh;
                }
        }
        }
```

VF Page -

```
<apex:page standardController="Work_Order__c" extensions="wrapper_test_controller">

    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageblock id="pb">       

        </apex:pageblockSection>
                 <apex:pageblocksection title="Products" >

               <apex:outputPanel title="Family">
               <apex:outputLabel value="Family:"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <apex:actionRegion >              
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedproductfamily}" size="1" label="Family"  rendered="true" >
                    <apex:actionSupport action="{!query}" reRender="pb1" id="fam" event="onchange"/> 

                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!productfamily}" />

                </apex:selectList>
                   </apex:actionRegion> 
                   </apex:outputLabel>
                   </apex:outputPanel>  
            </apex:pageblocksection>
         <apex:pageblocktable value="{!queryResult}" var="acc" id="pb1">
          <apex:column >
          <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
          <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Name}" />
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Family">
          <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Family}" />
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Measurement Type">
          <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Measurement_Type__c}" />
           </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Treatment Price">
           <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Treatment_Unit_Price__c}" />
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Cleaning Unit Price">
           <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Cleaning_Unit_Price__c}" />
           </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Service">
          <apex:repeatvalue="{!acc.work_order_items__R}" var="b">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!b.Service__c}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
          </apex:column>


          <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
          <apex:repeat value="{!acc.work_order_items__R}" var="b">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!b.Quantity__c}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
          </apex:column>

           <apex:column headerValue="Length">
           <apex:repeat value="{!acc.work_order_items__R}" var="b">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!b.Length__c}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
          </apex:column>

           <apex:column headerValue="Width">
           <apex:repeat value="{!acc.work_order_items__R}" var="b">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!b.Width__c}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
          </apex:column>  

          </apex:pageblocktable>

        </apex:pageblock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: on pageload in constructor add a blank record in queryResult  list..

Comment: hi ratan .. i want the blank field should come if there are no values.The above pic is an pageblocktable which is controller by a filter which is there in apex class..If it returns no value for service, length, width field it should display the picklist with none and a two blank textbox for length and width

Comment: Sid then I suggest use apex:outputField and inputField for all the columns.. SO basically if field is null then display inputField or if field is not null then display outputField using rerender attribute..

Comment: can u help me out  in this .. How to use apex:outputField and inputField on condition...

Comment: http://salesforce-walker.blogspot.in/2013/12/row-edit-and-save-using-wrapper-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Use inputtext instead of inputfiled!

Check if its a null then use inputtext.

Ex:

Instead of `<apex:inputfield value="{!b.Width__c}"/>`

use `<apex:inputtext value="{!b.Width__c}"/>`

Comment: Service column is a picklist. If i use input:text it wont show the picklist...

Answer (score 0):

you can do either way but I prefer {!variable != null}.

One thing that might often be a better idea though is to do the checks in the controller so that less of the logic is in the VF page.

EDIT: SObject booleans will always be true/false. It won't be null.

Comment: That is not displaying me any blank fields. From the above pic u can see as records displayed in 2nd row , i want same fields should be displyed in 1st row but it should be blank as it has no values..

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem in the repeat

```
<apex:repeatvalue="{!acc.work_order_items__R}" var="b">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!b.Service__c}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

How the list of work_order_items__R is empty you dont print the input field.

you need change the controller to add a new work_order_item__c if the list is empty.